# Return nil for a struct in Go

Tags: go

I am connecting to a database, getting a row and then sending it back to the user. What I want to do though is have a `return` statement if I can't find that row or if I have an error.

Because I'm returning a struct I can't return nil and I get that error `cannot use nil as type Item in return argument` (Item is my struct)

I read online that if I use a pointer in the return statement and return *Item instead of Item then I'd be able to pass nil, when I try to create `item := *Item{}` I get the following error `invalid indirect of Item literal (type Item)`

I think there are a few solutions to this but I can't find any, what I really want to know is:

- How to return a pointer *Item instead of Item
- Is there another way to return nil for a struct?

Here's my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"

  "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
  "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
  "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb"
  "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb/dynamodbattribute"
)

type Request struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

type Item struct {
  Name string `json:"name"`
  Stock int `json:"stock"`
  Price float64 `json:"price"`
}

func Handler(request Request) (Item, error) {
  sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
    Region: aws.String("us-west-2")},
  )

  // Create DynamoDB client
  svc := dynamodb.New(sess)

  result, err := svc.GetItem(&dynamodb.GetItemInput{
    TableName: aws.String("Inventory"),
    Key: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
      "name": {
          S: aws.String(request.Name),
      },
    },
  })

  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
//     return nil, err
  }

  item := Item{}

  err = dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalMap(result.Item, &item)

  if err != nil {
    panic(fmt.Sprintf("Failed to unmarshal Record, %v", err))
//     return nil, err
  }

  if item.Name == "" {
      fmt.Println("Could not find item")
//       return nil, nil
  }

  fmt.Println("Found item:")
  fmt.Println("Name:  ", item.Name)
  fmt.Println("Stock: ", item.Stock)
  fmt.Println("Price:  ", item.Price)

    return item, nil
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(Handler)
}
```

Comment: `item := *Item{}` should be `item := &Item{}`

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You're assigning your `item` variable wrong. You said you tried `item := *Item{}`, whereas the way to create a pointer is either through the use of the `new` builtin, or to create a literal, and the address-of operator (`&`). The latter is the approach you'll most commonly see in golang. There are some cases where one would use `new`, but in this case, I'd go for the second approach:

So either:

```
item := &Item{}
// or
item := new(Item)
```

Lastly, you can keep the code as-is, and just return a pointer at the end:

```
item := Item{}
// some code here
return &item, nil
```

In case where you have to return an error, you can still have `return nil, err`

So putting everything together:

```
// return *Item instead of Item
func Handler(request Request) (*Item, error) {
   // your code here, eg:
   item := Item{}
   if err := dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalMap(result.Item, &item); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return &item, nil
}
```

Alternatively, assign `item` as a pointer from the start

```
func Handler(request Request) (*Item, error) {
   // your code here, eg:
   item := &Item{}
   if err := dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalMap(result.Item, item); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return item, nil
}
```

Comment: This may be obvious but just to be sure OP ought to also update the return type from `Item` to `*Item` in the `Handler`s declaration.

Comment: @mkopriva: Updated, included the `UnmarshalMap` bit so `item` is being passed correctly based on how the var is initialised

Comment: Can someone explain *why* one cannot merely `return nil, err` without first declaring `item := &Item{}` or `item := Item{}`?

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer because `item` is passed as an argument to `UnmarshalMap`. If you don't declare it, you can't use it (ie pass it as an argument). You need the variable before you use it. If you don't want to allocate any memory unless you need to, just replace `item := Item{}`, with `var item Item`, pass it as `&item` to the `UnmarshalMap` call, and return `&item` on success, `nil` on error. `var item Item` won't allocate the object unless until it's needed, it's mentioned in the language spec somewhere.

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer nice one. `var item T` that is my answer :-)